# Django Rest Framework - perform Put request by passing a JSON object instead of just ID

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I'm working on a Project using Python(3), Django(1.11) and DRF(3.6) in which I have to perform a `PUT` request by passing a `nested nested` instead of an `ID`.

Here's What I have tried:

**`models.py`:**

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    login = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    avatar_url = models.URLField(max_length=500)


class Repo(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=500)


class Event(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    actor = models.ForeignKey(Actor, related_name='actor')
    repo = models.ForeignKey(Repo, related_name='repo')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

**`serializers.py`:**

```
class ActorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Actor
        fields = ('id', 'login', 'avatar_url')


class RepoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Repo
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'url')


class EventModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    actor = ActorSerializer(many=False)
    repo = RepoSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'type', 'actor', 'repo', 'created_at')
        depth = 1

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Event.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

> **Update:** Here when I submit a post request with the following object:

```
{
  "id":ID,
  "type":"PushEvent",
  "actor":{
    "id":ID,
    "login":"daniel33",
    "avatar_url":"https://avatars.com/2790311"
  },
  "repo":{
    "id":ID,
    "name":"johnbolton/exercitationem",
    "url":"https://github.com/johnbolton/exercitationem"
  },
  "created_at":"2015-10-03 06:13:31"
}
```

> it return this error as: `TypeError: 'ValueError: Cannot assign "OrderedDict([('id', '2790311'), ('login', 'daniel33'), ('avatar_url', 'https://avatars.com/2790311')])": "Event.actor" must be a "Actor" instance.`

**`views.py`:**

```
class Actor(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = EventModelSerializer
    queryset = EventModel.objects.all()

    def update(self):
        actor = EventModel.objects.filter(actor_id=self.request.data('id'))
        print(actor)
        return HttpResponse(actor)
```

**`Sample Input Object`:**

```
{
  "id":3648056,
  "login":"ysims",
  "avatar_url":"https://avatars.com/modified2"
}
```

The requirements is:
**Updating the avatar URL of the `actor`**: The service should be able to update the avatar URL of the actor by the PUT request at **`/actors`**. The actor JSON is sent in the request body. If the actor with the id does not exist then the response code should be `404`, or if there are other fields being updated for the actor then the HTTP response code should be `400`, otherwise, the response code should be `200`.**

> I'm little bit confused about how to perform the `PUT` request without
>   passing an `ID`?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your two-three questions asked today. I think You are asking the wrong question. I think what you need is three models `Event`, `actor` and `repo`. the `event` model has two foreign key fields as `actor` and `repo`. Now what you want it to update the `actor` models avtar_url field. OK?

```
class Actor(models.Model):
        avtar_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
       # Other Fields

class Repo(models.Model):
       # Other Fields

class EventModel(models.Model):
        id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
        type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        actor = models.ForaignKey(Actor)
        repo = models.ForaignKey(Actor)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

Now for create and update the **NESTED** `EventModel` entry use [writable-nested-serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers). By this, you can directly update the `avatar_url` for `Actor` by its id.

**UPDATE as per Request**

you need to change your `create` method as following so that it creates `Actor`, `Repo` and link their ids to `Event`

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        actor = validated_data.pop('actor')
        repo = validated_data.pop('repo')
        actor = Actor.objects.create(**actor)
        repo = Repo.objects.create(**repo)
        return Event.objects.create(actor=actor,repo=repo,**validated_data)
```

Comment: Hi @ashwin bande, I have updated my `models` and `serializers` but there another error comes in, how do I need to change my `serializers`?

Comment: now it returns `{
    "actor": [
        "Invalid pk \"{'id': 2790311, 'login': 'daniel33', 'avatar_url': 'https://avatars.com/2790311'}\" - object does not exist."
    ],
    "repo": [
        "Invalid pk \"{'id': 352806, 'name': 'johnbolton/exercitationem', 'url': 'https://github.com/johnbolton/exercitationem'}\" - object does not exist."
    ]
}`

Comment: I got it, there was a typo on my end.

Comment: SO is it working? if so Mark the answer as accepted so that others will know it is a working solution.

Comment: I stuck on the `update` method, how can I define the update?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188612/discussion-between-ashwin-bande-and-abdul-rehman).